# How to serialize xml files and compress them in memory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, serialization

I have written a code that serializes three XML documents and writes them to a local folder. I was wondering if it's possible to serialize them and save in memory instead of using local path ? Also, is it possible to zip those files "on the fly" so I can attach the zipped file to an email ? Here's the code I have so far, could someone give me a clue on how to amend this code so it does it all in memory?

```
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataCollectionXMLModel.ArrayOfCertQuestion));

 for (int i = 0; i < cachedList.Count; i++)
   {
       if (i == 0) documentName = "commonInformation.xml";
       if (i == 1) documentName = "contactInformation.xml";
       if (i == 2) documentName = "extraInformation.xml";

       StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Temp\\" + documentName);
       this.serializer.Serialize(writer, cachedList[i]);
       writer.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Without writing them locally? If not locally, where do you want the file to be written to? As long as it's a valid file path and you have the appropriate rights to that location, you can instruct `StreamWriter` to write to any location you want.

Comment: @Flater in memory for example? I just need to generate those files and compress them so theyre ready to be sent by email (all done by code) , not sure if that even possible thus my question

Comment: Fair enough, I forgot about in-memory writing. It's one of those things I learned during training but have so far never had to use it in over 6 years of professional experience :) Will look into an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use memory stream to write serialized data and create archive.

Example:

```
public class Program
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Tst
    {
        public string A { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Tst));

        var arr = new Tst[]
        {
            new Tst { A = "s1"},
            new Tst { A = "s2"},
        };

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var archive = new System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                {
                    var documentName = "def.xml";

                    if (i == 0) documentName = "commonInformation.xml";
                    if (i == 1) documentName = "contactInformation.xml";

                    var entry = archive.CreateEntry(documentName, CompressionLevel.NoCompression);

                    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(entry.Open()))
                    {
                        serializer.Serialize(writer, arr[i]);
                    }

                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```